# Configuring Sql Server job alerts to send email to users in a particular time

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have created a job alert for sending emails to user everyday. I have used Database mail and wrote a script to a send an email to users who falls in the particular category. 
But I want to send this email to the users only for three days. Email should be sent to the all users for three days only.

Updated:

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(20),
@birthdate datetime,
@email NVARCHAR(50),
@id nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @body NVARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE CC1 CURSOR READ_ONLY
FOR
SELECT Name, Birthdate, Email
FROM TestDB.dbo.cust
OPEN CC1
FETCH NEXT FROM CC1 INTO 
@name, @birthdate, @email
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @id= Ename  FROM TestDB.dbo.TestEmail
    IF @email = @id 
    BEGIN
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'vate',
    @recipients = 'vegeta@gmail.com',
    @body = 'The stored procedure finished successfully.',
    @subject = 'Automated Success Message' ;
    END
    FETCH NEXT FROM CC1 INTO 
    @name, @birthdate, @email
END
CLOSE CC1
DEALLOCATE CC1
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all when you create Job using Management Studio (Management Studio > SQL Server Agent > Jobs > New Job) you can create schedule on the Schedules tab.

When you have created Job using this wizard you can get SQL script to create this Job (with schedule) - Script button on the top of Wizard.

Here is a part of this script which create Schedule for a Job:

```
DECLARE @schedule_id int
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule @job_name=N'backup_job', @name=N'my_schedule', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @freq_type=8, 
        @freq_interval=7, 
        @freq_subday_type=1, 
        @freq_subday_interval=0, 
        @freq_relative_interval=0, 
        @freq_recurrence_factor=1, 
        @active_start_date=20140709, 
        @active_end_date=99991231, 
        @active_start_time=0, 
        @active_end_time=235959, @schedule_id = @schedule_id OUTPUT
select @schedule_id
GO
```

Comment: Good tips but I need help with sending emails to users for three days continuously. I need to set up a schedule for the task.

Comment: Please provide your code.  I don't see the problem now.  You can use active_start_date and active_end_date to set up schedule for three days continuously.

Comment: I don't know how to get the script from sql job agent.please tell me how.?

Comment: Each user will be receiving the emails for three days. If Raj gets the email for three days only, then the scheduler start sending the email to another user. Check my updated question. However I have not implemented the logic as I don't know how to..